# Umbraco custom plugin which interact with database

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am new in **Umbraco CMS**, I want to create a **custom module** which can interact with database and support **cross module interaction**.

Either it should be a new **Custom DataType** or Document type.

Note: I am using **Umbraco 7**

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi. You should ask a question related to difficulties with code. SO is not a forum site. It is a Q and A type site aimed specifically at problems with `code`. Do some research on the subject, and expand your question to include specific clarity and detail of what you are struggling with.

Comment: If you are looking for a forum about umbraco, look here: http://our.umbraco.org/